# How to add revision control to a Linux OS installation

Tags: software-rec, version-control

I have an SD card image of an Armbian based Linux system. I have done several modifications at different places to this system and I'm looking for a solution to add some versioning information to this system and/or to track the changes of the system based on a given zero state.

Are there any solutions to handle it?

Comment: I believe if this was asking whether solutions existed, rather than what good solutions existed, it wouldn't suffer the opinion-based closure votes...

Comment: IMO, "good" is just semantic noise in questions like this, short-hand for "what works?".  "Best" is asking for an opinion.   and either can be ignored if there's a decent question underlying it.

Comment: Personally, I configure all systems with [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/) and keep the ansible playbooks under version control (git).

Comment: NixOS does this far better than ansible/chef/puppet/etc. can, insofar as it doesn't try to manage state of an inherently-mutable system over time; instead, it forces the system to be defined in such a way that it transitions between immutable states. See https://nixos.org/ -- store your Nix code (that defines the system) in version control, make changes to the system by changing that code, and there you are; maybe store the actual derivations (.drv files, describing how each component of the system was constructed) if you're feeling extra paranoid.

Answer (score 5):

[etckeeper](https://etckeeper.branchable.com/) uses your choice of revision control system (e.g. `git`, `mercurial`, `brz`, etc) to keep a revision history of files in `/etc`.

On debian and debian-based systems, run `apt-get install etckeeper` to install it.  By default, it uses `git`.  The package also adds a daily cron job to run a commit regularly so you don't have to remember to, and it also adds hooks for `apt` to run a commit immediately before any apt install/upgrade/remove/purge/etc operation.

From the Package info:

```
Package: etckeeper
Version: 1.18.16-1
Depends: git | mercurial | brz | darcs, debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, python3:any
Recommends: cron-daemon
Suggests: sudo
Description-en: store /etc in git, mercurial, brz or darcs
 The etckeeper program is a tool to let /etc be stored in a git, mercurial,
 brz or darcs repository. It hooks into APT to automatically commit changes
 made to /etc during package upgrades. It tracks file metadata that version
 control systems do not normally support, but that is important for /etc, such
 as the permissions of /etc/shadow. It's quite modular and configurable, while
 also being simple to use if you understand the basics of working with version
 control.
```

BTW, with `git` as backend, you can configure a remote repo (e.g. with `git remote add ...`) so you can `git push` to it and have your /etc/ and its history backed up to another machine.   If you have multiple machines, give them all their own etc repo to push to.   I haven't used anything except `git` with it, but I expect the others will have some kind of remote ability.

You might also want to look into running something like [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/), [gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/), [gogs](https://gogs.io/), [git-repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo) or other similar tools to host git repos.   I would self-host this rather than use a public service, you don't want your `/etc/shadow` or other sensitive files to be accessible by some service provider or random people.

Comment: This tool will only create a backup of the `/etc` directory?

Comment: yep, that's what it does. it's in the name.   you'll need to use other tools (like rsync or tar) to backup other stuff.   programs like `rdiff-backup` can do versioned backups of the rest of the system (but IMO, you're better off with ZFS as the filesystem and using `zfs snapshot` and `zfs send`, especially for binary, non-text, data).

Comment: oh, and `etckeeper` doesn't "create a backup".  It keeps a revision history of changes in `/etc` - so you can easily see what changed and when it changed, or revert to a previous version of a config file, etc.   Backups are a different job (although, as I said, you can `git push` to a remote repo as a simple backup method).

Comment: ZFS sounds good. Can I use it on top of my ext4 filesystem (I. e. install some packages and ready to go) or do I have to create a new partition for it and move all the stuff to that partition?

Comment: No, ZFS is an alternative filesystem.   Switching to it requires backup, repartition/reformat as ZFS, restore.  `btrfs` has some similarities to zfs (including error-correction, transparent compression, snapshots and btrfs send) and there is a `btrfs-convert` utility to convert an existing ext3/ext4 filesystem to btrfs (I still wouldn't run this without a complete backup).   I have a very strong preference for zfs but btrfs is a pretty good second-place, especially if you have an existing ext4 fs that you're thinking of converting to RAID-1 - convert to btrfs instead, then add a second drive.

Comment: Another way to do it is to just add two or more drives to the system, create it as a zfs (or btrfs) pool and use that for your data (move and symlink most non-system data to the pool, or create subvolumes/datasets and mount them where they're needed).   BTW, both btrfs and zfs support transparent compression and snapshots so you can use raw disk-image files instead of qcow.  ZFS also has ZVOLs, which allow you to use some of the pool's space as a block device (which can be formatted and mounted as, e.g., a VM's virtual disk)